# Multithreading on yolo4

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, yolov4

I made this code finally work but I need to make it multithreaded because I am running it on a raspberry pi and runs really laggy. The pi is the 8gb ram pi4 model

This is the code, I only want to make it multi-threaded.Thanks a lot. Note that I am new to face recognition with python.

If you have the time, can you make suggestions for what I should improve?

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np

# This is a demo of running face recognition on live video from your webcam. It's a little more complicated than the
# other example, but it includes some basic performance tweaks to make things run a lot faster:
#   1. Process each video frame at 1/4 resolution (though still display it at full resolution)
#   2. Only detect faces in every other frame of video.

# PLEASE NOTE: This example requires OpenCV (the `cv2` library) to be installed only to read from your webcam.
# OpenCV is *not* required to use the face_recognition library. It's only required if you want to run this
# specific demo. If you have trouble installing it, try any of the other demos that don't require it instead.

# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
person_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("./faceRecognition/test.jpeg")
person_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(person_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    person_face_encoding,
]
known_face_names = [
    "individual"
]

# Initialize some variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    if process_this_frame:
        # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

        # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
            # if True in matches:
            #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
            #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

            # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame

    # Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask], but remember that this is not a tutorial website. If you have a *specific* problem, we'll be happy to help, but that's not your case: you don't know how to use treading and you're asking us to make your code for you; sorry, but that's not the scope of StackOverflow. Besides, if speed is your problem, multithreading will most probably **not** solve anything, as Python multithreading doesn't allow concurrency. Finally, please use tags correctly: your question has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are trying to solve? Do you have a specific performance target or do you just want it to be as fast as possible? Would it be possible for you to get more powerful hardware? What kind of camera are you using?